# Save raster layer temporal properties to qml

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, temporal-controller

Is there a way to save a raster's QgsRasterLayerTemporalProperties to a qml file using pyqgis?

I noticed that the temporal properties are also not included in the qml when manually saving the raster layer's style from Properties > Style > Save style..., so perhaps this is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the default method to save a style to qml ( `my_layer.saveNamedStyle('path_to_qml_file')` ) *does* also export the temporal properties to the file. However, due to a [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42223) (as of QGIS 3.16), the temporal properties are not always loaded from the qml file.